# Node.js addon singleton

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, design-patterns, singleton

I have a C++ addon for Node which I have to wrap into small js shim (library) and use it along with other modules in my project. The problem is, I have to maintain a single state for this addon (it's working with files, opening a lots of handles etc), so when I `require` it in one file and do some operations with it, I can be sure that when I will `require` it in another file it won't create all handles and execute all C++ constructing code again. How can I implement this? I thought about using a Singleton pattern in a shimming library, but I've read they don't play nice with `module.export`. Is it true? I'm using node 4.5+

Answer (score 0):

As far as singletons go, you could do it either at the C++ layer or at the JS layer.

In C++ it would just be a matter of creating/using globals and exporting functions that use those globals. Just make sure to take care of any race conditions that may arise if any of those exported C++ functions do any kind of async and/or multithreading.

In JS it would just be a matter of creating a single instance of whatever class is exported by the C++ addon and either directly exporting that same object, or if necessary, exporting functions that operate on the instance on behalf of the user.